# WAMP 2.5 X64 Not working

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit, wamp

I get the error...

```
The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer.
```

I have installed both Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package x64 and x32 bit.
I don't know what else to do. Because I'm still getting the error. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: It say's 1 of 2 services are running. And the little disk is orange. It should be green.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install the full Visual Studio Compile.

You need to have these MSVC runtimes installed, it looks like you were missing the MSVC11 (2012) runtime.

What you need :

```
The 2008 Redist (32bit) is used by wampmanager even if you installed the 64bit WAMPServer.
The 2010 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used ).
The 2012 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used ).
```

**FOR WAMP 32bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 32bit and therefore Apache 2.4.x**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 is required [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x86.exe

**FOR WAMP 64bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

> > Yes you need the x86 Package regardless as wampmanager uses this <<

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)  [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)  [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

**If you are using WampServer 2.4 or greater, 64bit**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)  And select vcredist_x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

Had to make sure that I had the correct versions of C++ installed as well as making sure port 80 was free.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the wamp server installation file as administrator (indeed for any installations). Doing this worked for me when previous installations resulted in not being able to launch wamp server.

Answer (score -1):

You can download everything here: https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/