# Missing MSCVR110.dll

Tags: wamp

I've downloaded the newest version of WAMP for the first time for my machine. It came with the error (something along the lines of): "missing MSVCR110.dll. Try reinstalling." Problem is I've installed everything, both 32 bit and 64 bit, every file listed and tried every verseion of WAMP but nothing suffices. I've copied the dll files into system32, changed the PATH etc. but nothing, please could someone help!

Comment: Try the 32 bit version. And undo the path chnages and the copy of stuff into system32 all that is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108122/wamp-2-5-x64-not-working). You need to download at least the MSVC11 runtime and possibly others as well

Comment: Thanks guys, but nothing works still, I'm now using a alternative called XAMPP and it works 1st time, I think WAMP is just poorly coded and need serious redoing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this get Xampp

Comment: If WAMPServers Apache needs MSVC 2012 then so does XAMPP's