# MSCVR110.dll missing from computer

Tags: wampserver

My computer has Windows 7 OS. I am failing to run `wamp server`.

It's displaying

```
The program can't start because MSCVR110.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.
```

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing MSCVR110.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677622/missing-mscvr110-dll)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4** also known as VC11. It is a runtime library used by any C/C++ program compiled with VC11, which the version of Apache is in WAMPServer 2.5.

Always download and install these DLL's from a Microsoft Site, never from sites like fix4dll, who know what you are downloading from there!

[Download and Install from this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

If you are running 64bit windows download and install both the 32bit and 64bit versions of this runtime. Remember 64bit windows runs 32 bit apps as well as 64bit ones.

```
VSU_4\vcredist_x86.exe  (32bit)
VSU_4\vcredist_x64.exe  (64bit)
```

Do this one at a time, so download one and then install it. Then the second one. Do it like this because the downloaded installer has a very similiar name and its easy to get confused.

If you are running 32bit Windows just download and install the 32bit runtime.

Because you did not have this DLL when you ran the WAMPServer install, the Apache service will not have been registered. So once this runtime library is installed you will have to do the following to get the Apache service running. Using `wampmanager`, the icon in the system tray do :-

```
(left click) wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
```

The Apache service should now be available to start using

```
(left click) wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Visual Studio C++ Redistributable 2012 should fix this problem. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=34673

If not, you can search for this DLL file in a DLL search web site, and then put it in your system 32 folder.

Comment: That link appears to be broken

Comment: Now its just wrong. You dont need the whole Visual Studio, all you need is the MSVC Runtime library. See my answer.