# wamp server is not working on the windows8

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I am installing wamp server 64 bit on my windows 8 system.I get following error "Application was unable to start correctly ( 0*c00007b)"

1) I have not installed the Skype

2) Port 80 is not being used by any program.

3) IIS service is not running on my system

4) I have tried re installing the wamp also

See screenshots
[image: error message]

[image]

Following is there in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

How to fix this.
Even though I start wamp server the icon never turn to green.

Do I need VC++ Redistributable?

**Solution**

I followed shiva's answer and installed 32 bit version.

Hope some one will post correct solution for this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108122/wamp-2-5-x64-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to find out that which service is using the post number 80, and close it and then run Apache(if something is using it).

alternately you can edit the `httpd.conf` file and change the port number ,by default it can be  found at this location

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf
```

In it  go to the line which has this entry(line 58 in WAMP server 2.4's installation)

`Listen 80`

and change it to something like this `Listen 8080`, and restart WAMP(or specifically Apache).

Now you will be able to access `localhost` like this

```
http://localhost:8080
```

**Update 1**

According to [this forum post](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,90472,90656), installing 32-bit version in place of 64 bit version,solved the issue in some cases

Comment: what to check using TCPView?

Comment: @Muk: I just included it in the answer, so you can make 100% sure that there is not other process using the Port number(although you have mentioned it already). Otherwise you the 2nd method and change the port number and check, if both methods fail it means that that you are installation failed to execute properly or there is some dependency missing.

Comment: @muk: I have updated the answer, and added a link, check that solution, that might help.